# How do I get a group (layer set) name in PS CS6 with Applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, photoshop

I can't figure out how I get a layer set name through applescript
and add this to a list. The list part of the question I think I've got,
but getting the actual name of the layer set is still a mystery.

```
set layerList to name of every layer set in current document where name contains ".png"
```

The code should go through every layer set in the file and add every set name containing ".png" to a list.

This is the error I currently get:

```
error "Adobe Photoshop CS6 got an error: Can’t get name of every layer set of current document whose name contains \".png\"." number -1728
```

I hope this explains my problem in a proper way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example code works fine in Photoshop CS5.1. Unfortunately I don't have CS6 around to test with, so you might want to examine a layer set's `properties` or take a peek at the dictionary entry for layer set.

Comment: @robjwells How would I go about examing a layer set's `properties`

Comment: `tell app 'Photoshop' \ tell the current doc \ get the properties of the first layer set`.  Minding my abbreviations, that will print out a record to AppleScript Editor's result panel. Check if the `name` property matches with what you expect from your Photoshop document.

Comment: @robjwells Thanks for the quick explanation, I was able to get all the properties from the layer set and the name property indeed was what I expected.

I figured out the problem occurs when the layer set I try to access resides in another layer set.